# Return type of lambda function `operator ()`

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, friend

Lambda function (or closure) in C++ is just an unnamed function object with `operator ()`. But what is the return type of that operator? The question becomes important if one wishes explicitly reference the full type of the operator e.g. for declaring it a friend.

For example, return type `auto`:

```
using V = decltype([](){});

class A{
    friend constexpr auto V::operator()() const;
};

int main(){
    V{}();
}
```

is accepted by Clang/MSVC but not GCC, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9fdzG94oK

And GCC requires friend declaration with deduced `void` return type here:

```
    friend constexpr void V::operator()() const;
```

which is in turn rejected by Clang/MSVC, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/naKaavndj

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: The standard is a bit vague here. It says [The lambda return type is `auto`, **which is replaced** by the type specified by the _trailing-return-type_ if provided and/or deduced from `return` statements as described in \[dcl.spec.auto\].](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.general#4.sentence-2) Well, `auto` is not a type, so it can't be "return type `auto`". And the "is replaced" part prolly didn't mean replacing the type in the declaration of `operator ()`. But it can be read this way.

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda): “`ClosureType`'s `operator()` cannot be named in a [friend](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declaration.”

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#15